# How to run command line argument using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am able to install the software from the Windows CMD with the following command

```
setup.exe -inputFile C:\my_installer_input.txt
```

However, I want to achieve the same above using the PowerShell script.

I tried same from the PowerShell like this

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Matlab R2018b\setup.exe" -inputFile "C:\my_installer_input.txt" -ArgumentList "/S
```

and it fails to run with the obvious reason `-inputFile` parameter is not available for `Start-Process` in PowerShell.

Comment: Your first commandline should work just fine in PowerShell as well. If you must use `Start-Process` you must pass the arguments to `setup.exe` as an array or string to the parameter `-ArgumentList`: `... -ArgumentList '-inputFile', 'C:\my_installer_input.txt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell also runs the native commands directly from PowerShell prompt, which means your command

```
setup.exe -inputFile C:\my_installer_input.txt
```

should work directly from the PowerShell prompt.

If you are executing on a remote machine, you can run with Invoke-Command as below.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { <YOUR CODE HERE> }
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <remote-computername> -ScriptBlock { <YOUR CODE HERE> }
```

Comment: I tried same above command and powershell is not recognizing the `setup.exe`.
`PS C:\Matlab R2018b (64 Bit)> setup.exe -inputFile C:\my_installer_input.txt`
setup.exe : The term 'setup.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ setup.exe -inputFile C:\my_installer_input.txt

Comment: `.\setup.exe -inputFile C:\my_installer_input.txt`, adding `.\` before setup.exe works fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If this is on a remote machine, do something like:

```
   Invoke-Command -Computername ‘x’ -Scriptblock {
Set-Location C:\path\to\file
    cmd /c setup.exe /arg1 /arg2
    }
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but (a) bringing remoting into the picture even though it wasn't asked for is a distraction and (b) there is no need for `cmd /c` - just invoke the target executable directly.